# SQL Server 2012 Database Timeout issues every couple of months

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a few SQL Server 2012 in our office. For this one, we have about 15 databases on it. Most of them are small, and used sparingly. A couple are for E-Commerce solutions, and others are for the  bulk of our business and are pretty busy. The issue is that it seems that around every couple of months, for what appears to be no reason, the Dell server hosting this will have a PMS day, and performance will slow to a crawl.

We've checked for extra or long running jobs. We've killed of replication and moved other busy databases to help aid in figuring out this problem. By this time tomorrow, it will most likely  have sorted itself out. But we don't get any error codes, just timeouts. We don't get deadlocks, and running and of the DMV's don't show any Locks or catches that would be indicative of an issue.   This server is running with 64gb RAM and 15K SAS drives.

Any monitoring is not showing any IO pressure or issues, making it even more  difficult to figure out. After digging around some more, we have identified the table that seems to be causing issues. Unfortunately, it's a main table and I'm not sure what I should be doing about it. We do daily full backups, 30 log backups, and 6 diff backups and nightly maintenance. Any Ideas would be grateful.

Comment: Queries that involve select from a single table in the database are all timing out.

Comment: Hmm, but you write that you have about 15 DBs on this server, and have identified a table as the problem. Is this table then present in all DBs, and if so, do they all "lock up"? I'm asking to try and clear up if it's the entire server acting up, or a singular DB.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "every couple of months" ?  for instance every 3 months could mean the quarterly finance reports are being executed manually. This won't appear as scheduled jobs.  Maybe some other scheduled activity is taking place.  Also, are the specific procedures that get "hung" or all procedures accessing the table.  If all, check for selects that don't utilize "with (nolock)".  Enough executions without it can cause a gradual "slow down" of the server as the duration time rises, but without appearing on the "db-lock" views, as they're not dead-locks, and are cleared after a time. Just not fast enough.  Also check your monitoring tools for the "number of executions" on procedures that access this table.